# No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.callWithAllRows() is applicable for argument types

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I'm calling a sql stored procedure via groovy method groovy.sql.Sql.callWithAllRows that doesn't require parameters and only returns a resultSet. But in issuing the following method w/ an empty enclosure it fails for "No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.callWithAllRows() is applicable for argument types" I assume you can make a callWithAllRows without sending parameters is that correct since the stored procedure doesn't require them?

Here is the call that fails:

```
    List<List<GroovyRowResult>> results = sql.callWithAllRows("{call 
    myStoredProcedure()}",[],{});
    results.each { result ->
        result.each { row ->
            row.each {                   
                println(it.FormalName.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

My Stored Procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure 
 AS
 BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 10 Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FormalName 
   FROM Person.Contact
 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
def rowsList = sql.callWithAllRows '{call myStoredProcedure()}',[],{
    result ->
}
```

Here is the reference: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#callWithAllRows(java.lang.String,%20List%3CObject%3E,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: I marked this as an answer. Somehow this works fine on my development system w/ Groovy 2.48, but in a deployed system w/ Groovy 2.19 it still fails for the same error. Is there a way to accomplish this same technique and retrieve the resultSet /w a call like this sql.call '{call myStoredProcedure()}',[],{
    result -> 
}

Comment: The problem is that in Groovy 2.1.9, the `call(Gstring gstring, List list, Closure closure)` returns `void`. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.1.9/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#call(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: If I am not wrong, the `ResultSet` is sent as the closure variable `result` in the `call` syntax. Probably as a map.

Comment: I don't the resultSet is part of the sql.call() enclosure. I'll have to post this in another question since I'm not how to do it using the sql.call() itself. It works fine using the sql.callWithAllRows. But, unfortunately I have to work with  groovy v2.19 that's deployed on our server and it can't upgraded =)